# check two conditions in two different columns in excel and count the matches

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I've trying to create a Error Log to help me analyse my mistakes. So for simplicity, lets assume I have two columns "Type of Question" - with values SC,RC,CR and another column that indicates whether I got this question "right/wrong".Let's assume this is my table:

Question No.   |   Right/Wrong    | Question Type

1. |     Right     |          SC
2. |     Right   |            RC
3. |  Wrong     |          SC
4. | Wrong |               CR
5. |  Right   |            RC

(Pardon my formatting skills).

And I want an output table like this

Type of Question    |  Right   |   Wrong  |  Total

SC                   |  1      |      1     |   2

RC                    |   2     |       0     |   2

CR                     |  0      |      1    |    1

So basically what I want to do is check Column3 for SC using =COUNTIF(C1:C5,"SC"), and return the total number of SC questions, and then outta the SC , I need to find out which are Right.If I know the right and the total I can get the wrong.

I have never written a macro so a formula based answer would suffice.

Comment: If you are using excel 2007 or later look into `Countifs`

Answer (score 4):

[COUNTIFS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx) lets you specify several criterias.

In your case `=COUNTIFS(C1:C5;"SC";B1:B5;"Right")`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with SUMPRODUCT even in Excel 2003 and earlier versions, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT((C1:C5="SC")*(B1:B5="Right"))`